# What is the "Starting Point" For PHP's set_include_path

Tags: php

What is set_include_path Relative to, in PHP?  Is it the folder where the PHP.exe resides?  Is it the webroot?  In other words, what folder would set_include_path('/') or set_include_path('.') be referring to?

Comment: GZipp made the following suggestion, which was extremely useful for me:

Try running a test script - set_include_path('/'); echo realpath(get_include_path());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative paths are resolved from the location of the file where `include` or another function that uses *include_path* is used in (see [description of *include_path*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)):

> Using a `.` in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use `include './file'` than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

`/` would describe the root of your filesystem and `.` the current directory.

Comment: @Joshua - Try running a test script - set_include_path('/');
echo realpath(get_include_path());

Comment: Thank you!  realpath is exactly what I needed all along!

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem root and the current directory, [respectively](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Comment: By file system root you mean C:\?

Comment: If your web server et alia are running off C:, sure.

Comment: My web server is running off of X:, which is a shared folder on C: mapped to X:

Answer (score 1):

set_include_path("/") would make the include path be the root folder of the filesystem, and I would take a guess that you'd probably not want to do that as there might be issues with exposing files that you don't want to be seen.

If your php file was /home/users/joebloggs/htmlroot/index.php, then set_include_path(".") would make the include path the directory that the php file is in, ie the "htmlroot" directory.

Answer (score 0):

On *nix systems and Windows Apache the / is the root of the file system. While on IIS / points to the root of the vhost.

What I do to handle this is define a LOC constant in my index.php so I never get confused when including files.

```
define('LOC', dirname(__FILE__));
include(LOC . '/files/file.php');
```